# Context Menu Jquery Per Object Pass Parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

I Have list Of Record from database, I want every record have commands (like : update, delete, clear, etc)
I use [ContextMenu.js v 1.2.2](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu)
this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/contextMenu.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/contextMenu.css'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myDelete(ID){
            // do something with ID
        }
        function myUpdate(ID){
            // do something with ID
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var menu = [{
                name: 'delete', img: 'images/delete.png', title: 'Delete Button', disable: 'false',
                fun: function () {
                    alert('i am delete button')
                }
            },{
                name: 'note', img: 'images/update.png', title: 'note button', disable: 'false',
                fun: function () {
                    alert('i am note button')
                }
            }];
            $('.testMenu').contextMenu(menu);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="tablesorter" id="tabel-rekap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>Name 1</th>
            <th><div class="testMenu"><img src="images/someimages.png" /></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>Name 2</th>
            <th><div class="testMenu"><img src="images/someimages.png" /></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>Name 3</th>
            <th><div class="testMenu"><img src="images/someimages.png" /></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>Name 4</th>
            <th><div class="testMenu"><img src="images/someimages.png" /></div></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is How to pass the **ID** Parameter to my functions (delete, update, etc) ?

Comment: On which event you want to execute `myDelete()` function?

Comment: @MangeshParte : when user click item delete in context menu.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your code?